# Django Select2 Widget bad rendering?

Tags: django, web-applications, jquery-select2, django-select2

I tried to implement multi select-boxes from select2. The widget works fine, but the user input is under the field.

Screen:
[image]

this how it looks in html.

```
<select class="js-example-basic-multiple" name="states[]" multiple="multiple">
            
        <option value="AL">Something</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
        <option value="WY">Somebody</option>
        </select>
    
     
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2();
        });

    </script>
```

I tried to change height, but maybe not its the problem

Comment: Make sure you have imported the select2 css file correctly. This is a CSS issue, not Django issue.

Comment: thanks, i changed version and now its working correctly